# Why my API-Key format is considered invalid?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, binance, vpc, ccxt

This is the code I'm using, it runs on **google cloud function** and uses the **ccxt** library

```
import ccxt
import json

def get_binance_balance(request):
    try:
        
        api_key = 'MY_API_KEY'
        secret_key = 'MY_SECRET_KEY'
        
        
        # Set up Binance client using ccxt
        binance = ccxt.binance({
            'apiKey': api_key,
            'secret': secret_key
        })
        
        # Fetch the account balance
        balance = binance.fetch_balance()

        # Create a dictionary to store the account balance information
        account_balance = {}

        # Store the account balance in the dictionary
        for asset, info in balance['total'].items():
            if info > 0:
                account_balance[asset] = info

        # Return the account balance as a JSON response
        return json.dumps(account_balance)

    except Exception as e:
        error_message = str(e)
        return json.dumps({'error': error_message})
    except ccxt.BaseError as e:
        # Handle specific ccxt errors
        print("ccxt error:", e)
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        # Handle specific requests library errors
        print("requests error:", e)
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle other general exceptions
        print("Error:", e)
```

However every time i try to execute the code it just gives this link:
`https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/capital/config/getall`

Which lead to this error:
`{"code":-2014,"msg":"API-key format invalid."}`

For what i could see online it seemes like it is **an header problem**, however **ccxt should take care** of all of that, in fact if i were to replace ccxt.binance with ccxt.coinbasepro this problem wouldn't occure.

Could it be because Google Cloud IP can't get access to the Binance API? (My function operates on a server in Zurich)

Also my function uses a **VPC** since otherwise Binance would ,also, give this error:

> Service unavailable from a restricted location according to 'b. Eligibility' in https://www.binance.com/en/terms. Please contact customer service if you believe you received this message in error`

If you can find the solution to this problem i would appreciate it a lot, I have been trying to fix it for hours, not joking.